# Clarification of the parameter "alpha"

Tags: python, pandas

The Pandas [`ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) function (Exponentially Weighted Moving Average/Stddev/etc.) takes a parameter `alpha`.

If I understand the intent correctly, this parameter `alpha` is used to multiply previous values before adding the current value to calculate the value of the function.

For example, in the case of the mean: the next value of the mean is given by the previous value multiplied by alpha, plus the next data value:

```
mean_next = mean_previous * alpha + next_data
```

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually

```
mean_next = alpha * next_data + (1 - alpha) * mean_previous
```

Comment: Makes sense - I was assuming there would be a weight accumulator as well.  Thanks for clarifying - this formula is more elegant than what I had in mind. Also alpha is the reverse way around to what I had thought? Meaning larger alpha = faster decay time rather than slower? I suppose that should have been obvious to me from some of the other functions

Comment: The docs for `ewm` do call `alpha` the decay parameter, so that's indeed the case.

Comment: Sure but that says nothing about whether a larger value implies faster or slower decay. For something like a half-life it would be pretty un-ambigious. It isn't immediatly obvious looking at the equation for alpha in terms of the halflife which way round it it. The only way to know is to differentiate it or plug in some numbers. Or take a limit I suppose. It really isn't obvious